# Alternate to translate for vertically centering elements

Tags: html, css

I made a [responsive login form](http://jsfiddle.net/Lw2dsj4y/) using CSS3 `translate` but I found problems in an old phone. Any alternative to CSS3 translate? I just want to center vertically.

```
.loginPage-wrap{
   padding: 10px;
   position: absolute;
   bottom: 0;
   -ms-transform:translate(-50%);
   -webkit-transform: translate(-50%);
   transform: translate(-50%);
   left: 50%;
   width: 92%;
   box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Lw2dsj4y/)

Comment: I think you mean you want to center horizontally?

Comment: Improved code formatting, reworded the title a bit. Since CSS and CSS3 are tagged, it need not be mentioned again in the title. Please describe what was the problem on the old phone and maybe even add details like what was the browser etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would the following code work?

```
.loginPage-wrap {
    padding: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left:-46%;
    width: 92%;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/va6y8713/)
Let me know if it works.

Comment: it seem worked.. but will this work in different size screen?

Comment: It should. The main thing to note is that you need to apply a negative margin to the class which is one half of its width. So if the width of it changes in different media queries be sure to compensate with your margin :)

Comment: Adjust your screen size in the fiddle and see it in action.

Comment: so this trick will work if want to center horizontal using position absolute? sometime I try it didn't work.

Comment: It should work in many instances. Of course it depends on the exact position you want to achieve based on parent containers. But is this example working for you? Can you provide an example where it is not working?

Comment: I advise adding a min-width, just in case. Something like `.loginPage-wrap {min-width: 280px;}`.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a multidevice solution using css display table property:

```
.column-wrapper { display: table; width: 100%; height: 100vh; }
.col-1, .col-2 { display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle; }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/93n2e9a0/

Another way will be using flexbox (to use in iOS you must prefix css options with -webkit-, but it's compatible in old devices with old flexbox): 
https://jsfiddle.net/5oh5mhbw/

Flex tutorial: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: Note that [`vh`](http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units) won't work in older (mobile) browsers, nor will [`flexbox`](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox).

Comment: Yes, I know, I used vh because is a demo site, in a real project his column will be higher with the content that hi put on it.